# Sentinel values for the first iteration of a loop?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, sentinel

Imagine the following pseudocode

```
objects[i], 1 <= i <= n 

objects[0] = 0

for i from 1 to n
  if(objects[i] - objects[i-1] > constant)
    do something
```

I'd like to know if there's a specific name for the assignment `objects[0] = 0`.
I know that when values like these are used to stop loops, they are called sentinel values.
In this case, however, I'm using it so that the first object evaluated (objects[1]) will have something to compare against - obviously, `objects[0]` is not a real object, just sort of a flag. Is it still called a sentinel value? Is there another name for this? Or should I not be doing this at all?

Let me know if I haven't made myself clear and I should try to explain my question in another way.

Comment: "Sentinel value" is fine IMO.  Or maybe "boundary condition"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cormen et al. writes in *Introduction to Algorithms* (3rd ed.) on page 238:

> A sentinel is a dummy object that allows us to simplify boundary
>   conditions.

This definition is broad enough to account for your usage (e.g. sentinel values of infinity are used in CLRS to simplify the merge routine of mergesort).

Answer (score 1):

I've always called it a "sentinel" whether at the beginning or the end, and haven't yet been fired for that.

Comment: But this does not match the definition of a sentinel value at all: "a special value whose presence guarantees termination of a loop" (from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

Comment: @dcastro: Cormen et al. writes "A sentinel is a dummy object that allows us to simplify boundary conditions."

Comment: @Nabb: Ah, that settles it then. All the other definitions I've found do not account for these cases. This is actually for my masters thesis and that citation is very helpful. Would you put it as an answer so I could accept it?